# I try to build a document editor with CKEditor5 classiceditor, but it is not editable

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I create a project to implement stand alone CKEditor5 as a document editor. Here is my project:

http://github.com/viraweb123/vw-document/

The problem is, the CKEditor is not editable?! I try to change the readonly option, but it did not work.

---

All contents are placed in a DIV with following classes:

```
ck-restricted-editing_mode_restricted 
ck 
ck-content 
ck-editor__editable 
ck-rounded-corners 
ck-editor__editable_inline 
ck-blurred
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I enable the Restricted Editing module by accident, and the document is loaded in the restricted mode?! For more information see:

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/restricted-editing.html

I just remove the plugin and the editor runs in standard mode. :)